# Rails 5 Migration Data Type Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, mariadb

I originally developed my rails 5 application using PostgreSQL. I had to change over to a MariaDB after I had done all of my development due to some issues with hosting.

I'm trying to put in an update that adds a reference to the admin from my shopping cart. Here is my migration:

```
class AddAdminRefToCart < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :carts, :admin, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

when I run

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get this error:

```
== 20171129152942 AddAdminRefToCart: migrating ================================
-- add_reference(:carts, :admin, {:foreign_key=>true})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Column `admin_id` on table `carts` has a type of `bigint(20)`.
This does not match column `id` on `admins`, which has type `int(11)`.
To resolve this issue, change the type of the `admin_id` column on `carts` to be :integer. (For example `t.integer admin_id`).
```

The error makes sense but I am unsure of the proper way to fix the issue. Can someone please give some guidance on how I should write my migration? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just specify the exact data type you want, instead of using `add_reference`.

```
add_column :carts, :admin_id, :integer, limit: 4
add_foreign_key :carts, :admins
```

The `limit: 4` parameter is telling the database to create a 4-byte field, which would correspond to INT, as opposed to `limit: 8` (apparently the default now), which would correspond to BIGINT.

As I mentioned in the comments, this will not create any issues by not using `add_reference`, since `add_reference` is just "syntactic sugar" for `add_column` and, optionally, `add_index` and `add_foreign_key`.

Comment: Does this cause any issues with Rails though? Will expected rails functionality stop working due to not using add_reference in the relationship?

Comment: Not at all. `add_reference` is just syntactic sugar for `add_column` and, optionally, `add_index` and `add_foreign_key`.